# Tilting the camera towards a specified direction in Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, quaternions

hey yall i need some help, ive been trying to figure out how to make my camera tilt towards a specific direction correctly but been having some weirdness to it. specifically its in the direction my player has been hit, [like in this video describing how minecraft used to have this tilting camera to express where damage was taken from](https://www.youtube.com/embed/pAJPc71YOnY?start=37)

my idea was to collect the direction the attack was from, get the cross product of it and transform.up to get an axis i can rotate around, and then use Quaternion.AngleAxis to tilt my camera in that direction, but with this implementation it doesn't seem to react to me turning around in place, always tilting in the same odd direction

this is my script that handles being attacked and initiates the camera tilting

```
// Vector3 punchSource is from attack instance
Vector3 punchPosition = new Vector3(punchSource.x, transform.position.y, punchSource.z);
Vector3 punchDirection = (punchPosition - transform.position).normalized;
Vector3 crossAxis = Vector3.Cross(punchDirection, transform.up);
pa.punchRotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(45f, crossAxis);
```

and this is whats relevant in my camera controller

```
public Quaternion punchRotation;
...
punchRotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(punchRotation, quaternion.identity, 45f * Time.deltaTime);
...
cameraRotation += punchRotation.eulerAngles;
transform.eulerAngles = cameraRotation;
```

and an example of my problem

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KDGoH.jpg

Comment: I am ancient so pardon me but I think you can find out the angle between Player's z-axis and (enemyPos - playerPos) and rotate Camera around its own z-axis by that angle.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the animation in Unity, Start recording and try to move your camera as you like. you can save that clip. This way you have full control of how you want the camera to shake. Trigger it every time that your character is attacked. You can also check out cinemachine

Comment: no animations here sadly its supposed to be script driven so it can react appropriate to the right direction the player was hit and give indication instead of being a premade animation. not sure if default camera is to blame/cinemachine will help either i think its more so the math that i need help with

Comment: punchRotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(punchRotation, quaternion.identity, 45f * Time.deltaTime); if you want the camera to move to the direction that is being hit by, currently you are saying quaternion.identity which is stay put. Maybe that's why it is not facing the correct direction

Comment: but RotateTowards works to move the rotation from punchRotation (my tilt goal) to quaternion.identity to clear my tilt after the fact. this seems to work fine as my camera does tilt in some way and does return to quaternion.identity after. maybe ur confused in thinking i wanted the camera to stay facing the target? its the punchRotation that feels odd and not changing depending on my rotation

Comment: I just take a look at the video you post, it seemed the Minecraft video is more like the monster adds force to the character's body and causes the character's body to float a bit instead of just shaking the camera.

Comment: yea i think thats just a matter of physics and calculating knockback of sorts, but my goal is to just get the damage tilt to work correctly like how [in my example the tilt doesnt change based on direction](https://imgur.com/a/p9gza4v)

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be looking for [Transform.LookAt](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.LookAt.html) on any script attached to the object that you want to another object, simply call transform.LookAt(target) in the update function and your object will rotate to the target. **This WILL make your object rotate on the x, y and z so if you want restrictions, you'll need to add those.**

Also, another answer is talking about how to do a very complicated version of this to record a video. If you are looking to make a video, simply run your scene, then go to your scene manager and you can use the right mouse button, mouse movements and the WASD keys to traverse your scene like a floating orb.

Comment: not sure if LookAt may be the thing im entirely looking for, since I'm not looking to face the attacker but merely tilt towards them for a moment on top of my already existing rotation but if u have more explanation on how this could work ill appreciate it !! also no clue what the second part means im not trying to record a video its just a camera tilt during gameplay

Comment: Then perhaps you want to create an invisible object in front of your camera which is the target of LookAt, then use velocity to move and return the object to give an imitated glance.

Comment: with that though how would i rotate the camera to give that imitated glance with LookAt? like how do i figure out how to just tilt or pitch the camera down towards a vector3, without changing the direction it faces? it feels like LookAt kinda just sidesteps my problem since it only tells me how to face towards a direction and change my transform.forward

Comment: If you don't want to or can't deal with rotations, then just place an object where you want to look without any renderer on it and look at it..... This answer is definitely a sidestep. Understanding quaternions and rotations would be your best bet.